# Why doesn't my local map show roads?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning, windows-7

I seem to be having an issue with my local map in *Kingdoms of Amalur: Reckoning*.

[image]

As you can see, it shows the proper icons, but it doesn't show the actual *roads*. This makes planning my route to my next quest objective (or even finding my way) extremely difficult.

I did notice, however, that whenever I first entered an area (specifically a cave), I was met with this map:

[image]

Well, wait a minute. What's this? Everything is shown. But, whenever I proceed further into said cave:

[image]

Aww... Nuts.  (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

**How can I fix this map?**

**EDIT**
It seems to work just fine upon leaving an area (such as the cave in the pictures above). Once I reach a certain distance from the cave entrance, however, it returns to the black background with various icons shown.

Comment: Have you tried reloading the game? What system are you on?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Playing it on the PC. Windows 7, Intel HD integrated graphics, 6 GB of RAM... Don't know if that's pertinent information. I've tried re-installing.

Comment: This is happening with me for once in a while. I need to keep reopening the map until it is properly rendered. My graphic card is an *Intel® HD Graphics 3000* (which runs this game just fine, except for the map issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try turning off graphical options. I know that some ATI cards have bugged out when Post Processing is enabled.

Comment: Sure enough, it was the Post Processing.